# SmartAssembly Consol

Tags: smartassembly

Does any one know how to write this line in post build event

```
call "C:\Program Files\Red Gate\SmartAssembly 6\SmartAssembly.com" "/build $(ProjectFolder)\($ProjectName).saproj" "/input=$(TargetPath) /output="%USERPROFILE%\AppData\Roaming\$(ProjectName).bundle\Contents\$(ConfigurationName)\$(TargetName)"
```

I keep Getting Exited with Code 1.

Answer (score 0):

Just add the following line in the `Post build event`:

```
"C:\Program Files\Red Gate\SmartAssembly 6\SmartAssembly.com" /build "full_path.saproj"
```

We put the output and input already inside the saproj file and use no flags

I think the error is here:

```
"/build $(ProjectFolder)\($ProjectName).saproj"
```

should be:

```
/build "$(ProjectFolder)\($ProjectName).saproj"
```

Also - see this [link](https://documentation.red-gate.com/display/SA6/Using+SmartAssembly+with+MSBuild) from red gate web page